# Trying to understand stock share dilution

Tags: united-states, investing, private-company, dilution

Say I pay $100,000 for 10% of a new company founded by a entrepreneur, and then the entrepreneur decides to give 20% of the business to person X, for free, as they feel person X can add tremendous value to the business. Can they dilute me? Or would they have to give the full 20% from their 90% share?

Can an entrepreneur issue new shares for the company and dilute me like this?

**If Q is unclear please comment I will clarify.**

Comment: You need to ask him exactly where those shares are coming from.  A company’s board of directors *can* vote to sell “authorized but unsold” shares.

Comment: @RonJohn Why should there be a board of directors, the entrepreneur makes all the desicisons cause he owns much more than 50%.

Comment: Corporations **must** have a board of directors.  It’s the law.

Comment: @RonJohn So you mean the board of directors can issue new shares and give it away for free? How many people must such a board have?

Comment: Added a comment there @keshlam

Comment: Corporations are like republics, where shareholders annually vote on board members, who then do things like choose the CEO and President, decide on dividends, decide what to do with unissued shares of stock, etc.  As a 10% shareholder, you *would* get a seat on the board of a large company, since they have lots of board members.  And then there's the **Annual Shareholder Meeting**, where you can officially raise such issues.  But as long as he has 50.1% of the shares, he can always get his way (except when the corporate bylaws say that certain votes require a 2/3 or 3/5 majority.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> the entrepreneur decides to give 20% of the business to person X, for free, as they feel person X can add tremendous value to the business

Yes that would dilute your *percentage* but not necessarily your *value*. Note that this seems to be an extraordinary example as the more typical example would be to *sell* the shares for their current value. In that case, your value would stay the same since you would own a smaller portion of a larger pie.

If instead that used shares as an incentive to employ someone else, then (assuming there's not fraud or stupidity involved) presumably that person would add an equivalent amount of value to the company, which would benefit you as well. So it's the same principle. If the present value of X's contributions was worth the same as the shares they're given, then you would still own a smaller portion of a larger pie (i.e. you would own a portion of the future benefits that person X brings). Now, if that person underperforms, that's bad for you as a shareholder, but it would be bad for you if they instead raised cash and used that cash unwisely.

That's much harder to quantify than a direct cash sale, but the principle is the same.

> Can an entrepreneur issue new shares for the company and dilute me like this?

That's more of a *legal* question and it depends on the by-laws of the company and the laws in their jurisdiction, but it's not unusual for companies to issue more shares provided that have the approval of the board of directors and the existing shareholders, based on the by-laws of the company.  Such issues *can* be dilutive but not always. Certainly fraud *can* happen which makes it important that you fully understand whatever you're investing in.

Comment: Thanks that’s helpful, is it possible for them to only dilute me and not dilute themselves when they issue new shares and sell them? In other words the entrepreneur considers himself to be the person X.

Comment: Well I suppose there could be _some_ scheme to "gift" themselves extra ownership, but it would almost certainly be either explicitly illegal or fraudulent, both of which would be something to resolve in court. In other words, you could likely sue them for actual damages for diluting your _value_.

Comment: Why don’t they just make it illegal to sell shares below the valuation a shareholder invests at?

Comment: @Shinrin-Yoku the board of directors have wide latitude in issuing new shares.  It's part of the corporate bylaws.

Comment: @Shinrin-Yoku for one thing, because the company might now be worth less than at the time of the investment (e.g. lookup "down valuation" in the context of VC funding)

Comment: @Shinrin-Yoku Because companies can lose value without fraud being involved. Equity investment is by no means guaranteed - it's only illegal if there is fraud involved. Sometimes selling shares below current market value can be _good_ if it adds value to the company in other ways.